# sh: symfony-cmd: command not found

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony-flex

I have downgraded a Symfony 5.2 app template to use Symfony 4.4 in order to allow the use of some libraries that require an older version of Symfony. The problem is that when I do `composer install`, I get this error near the end of the installation:

> sh: symfony-cmd: command not found

It seems that the installations are mostly successful, as my `vendor` folder is created and populated. But I'm worried about the error.

**What does this error mean? How do I fix it?**

====

Edit: Here's my `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.4.0",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "1.11.99.1",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.7",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.4",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.1",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.9",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "*",
        "symfony/intl": "*",
        "symfony/mailer": "*",
        "symfony/mime": "*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/notifier": "*",
        "symfony/process": "*",
        "symfony/property-access": "*",
        "symfony/property-info": "*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/serializer": "*",
        "symfony/string": "*",
        "symfony/translation": "*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/validator": "*",
        "symfony/web-link": "*",
        "symfony/yaml": "*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "*",
        "twig/twig": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.4",
        "roave/security-advisories": "dev-master",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "*",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "*",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "*",
        "vimeo/psalm": "^4.9"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.2.*"
        },
        "patches": {
            "symfony/maker-bundle": {
                "Provide flag to force annotation in make entity command": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vklux/maker-bundle-force-annotation/master/maker-force-annotation-flag.patch"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`symfony-cmd` is a part of Symfony Flex. Your `composer.json` does not contain any requirement for Flex, so running `composer require symfony/flex`  might resolve that problem.

Comment: While I ran into some recursive problems with `composer require`, adding that requirement to the `composer.json` file was enough to fix the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 32):

For those who have the `symfony/flex` package installed and are still getting the error, make sure the `symfony/flex` package is allowed to execute code when running composer.

This is because since Composer 2.2.0 the `allow-plugins` option adds a layer of security that allows you to restrict which Composer plugins can execute code at startup time.

So make sure you have the appropriate line in the `allow-plugins` config in your `composer.json` file

```
"config": { 
    // other config...

    "allow-plugins": {
        "symfony/flex": true
    }
},
```

Comment: this did the trick! thanks!

Comment: That also did the trick for me. I also had to add `"symfony/runtime": true` in the list of allowed plugins,

Answer (score 5):

While adding symfony/flex to the project is one solution, keep in mind that Flex is optional. If you want to get rid of the error without installing Flex, simply remove the symfony-cmd command references from your composer.json.

Before:

```
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
```

After:

```
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {},
        "post-install-cmd": [],
        "post-update-cmd": []
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

as addition, we just ran into this issue in docker which runs as root. since composer 2.7 plugins are disabled when running as root.

to bypass this check, set the following environment variable:

```
COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
```

https://github.com/composer/composer/releases/tag/2.7.0

> Fixed automatic disabling of plugins when running non-interactive as root

Comment: It's important to note that the primary cause of this error is because of running composer as a root user and simply bypassing this with the environment variable, or running as a non-root user is the solution to the majority of those experiencing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a special case were an old deploy script added `--no-plugins` to my composer command. Removing that solved my issue with using deployer v6.

`set('composer_options', '{{composer_action}} --verbose --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-interaction --no-dev --optimize-autoloader');`

Apparently you need plugins for flex to work, and I'm assuming since the scripts block has some commands you need that too. So having no script/plugins will break your installation.